# Docker compose do not exit depends_on containers on exit. Why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to figure out why docker compose leaves the depends_on containers up when the main container exits. This is my setup:

If I run this command `docker compose run --rm --service-ports --build --entrypoint /usr/bin/fish shop-server` and then exit the `shop-server` container, it still remains `shop-db` up and is not removed (even if the `--rm` flag is specified).

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

name: dev

services:
  shop-server:
    container_name: shop-server-${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
      - ./tmp/fish-shop-server/:/root/.local/share/fish/
      - /tmp/shop_debug.log:/tmp/shop_debug.log
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - ${DJANGO_PORT}:${DJANGO_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - shop-db
    env_file: .env

  shop-db:
    container_name: shop-db-${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./tmp/fish-shop-db/:/root/.local/share/fish/
    ports:
      - ${SQL_PORT}:${SQL_PORT}
    env_file: .env

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because it was not design to. It's hard to answer why something does not happen, it doesn't happen, because its not there. Where specifically in documentation does it state that depends on containers will be stopped? Also, you are doing nothing wrong (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong here, but `depends_on` does not intend to shut down depending on services when you exit another one.

As stated in the [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#depends_on), `depends_on` is used to control the *startup* *order* in a compose file containing multiple services.

> Compose guarantees dependency services have been started before starting a dependent service. Compose waits for dependency services to be "ready" before starting a dependent service.